# PL/SQL How to obtain count of the table I am querying from? How to use NEW with COUNT?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

below is my code that will trigger when a new row in Trip is inserted. Then it will update on the column totalTripMade in the Driver table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_TOTAL_TRIPS_MADE
AFTER INSERT
      ON TRIP
      FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE 
    tripsDone NUMBER(6);
    driverL# NUMBER(12);

BEGIN
    --Find the L# of the Driver performing the INSERT into the Trip table
    SELECT D.L# INTO driverL#
    FROM DRIVER D
    WHERE D.L# =: NEW.L#;

    --Find the number of trips done by the driver (Error occured here)
    SELECT COUNT(T#) INTO tripsDone
    FROM TRIP T
    WHERE NEW.L# =: driverL#;

    --Then update the totaltripmade by the driver
    UPDATE 
        DRIVER
    SET
        totalTripMade = tripsDone
    WHERE
        L# = driverL#;
END UPDATE_TOTAL_TRIPS_MADE;
/
```

However, there is compilation error due to not able to query TRIP until the trigger is completed.
So, I tried changing the select count statement to like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO tripsDone
FROM TRIP T
WHERE driverL# =: NEW.L#;
```

But it did not work too. I am not sure how can I work around to get the total number of rows in the table Trip with the driverL# that triggered the trigger.

Comment: Both two select statements have no sense. Since the first returns the same value with `: NEW.L#`(provided has no multiple values in the driver table, otherwise, even too_many_rows exception raises). There's no column from the table in the WHERE condition of the second query. Moreover, why do you need holding a data which can already be returned from a query ?

Comment: Why do this at all? Can't you just select the count of the trips from TRIP when you need to know?  Storing a value that can easily be derived from other existing data is very poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this problem, you should probably NOT use a trigger.  Just write a query for counting the "trips".  Example:

**Tables**

```
create table driver (
  id number generated always as identity start with 1 primary key
, surname varchar2( 50 )
-- , ttm number -- total trips made: redundant!
) ;

create table trip (
  id number generated always as identity start with 1000 primary key
, from_ varchar2( 50 )
, to_   varchar2( 50 )
, driver number references driver( id )
) ;
```

**Test data: DRIVER**

```
insert into driver( surname )
select 
  'driver_' || to_char( level )
from dual
connect by level <= 10 ;

select * from driver ;
  ID SURNAME     
   1 driver_1    
   2 driver_2    
   3 driver_3    
   4 driver_4    
   5 driver_5    
   6 driver_6    
   7 driver_7    
   8 driver_8    
   9 driver_9    
  10 driver_10
```

**Test data: TRIP**

```
begin
  for i in 1 .. 10
  loop
    insert into trip ( from_, to_, driver ) values ( 
      'departure_' || to_char( i )
    , 'arrival_' || to_char( i )
    , mod( i, 3 ) + 1
    ) ;
  end loop ;
  commit ;
end ;
/

SQL> select * from trip ;
    ID FROM_          TO_            DRIVER 
  1000 departure_1    arrival_1           2 
  1001 departure_2    arrival_2           3 
  1002 departure_3    arrival_3           1 
  1003 departure_4    arrival_4           2 
  1004 departure_5    arrival_5           3 
  1005 departure_6    arrival_6           1 
  1006 departure_7    arrival_7           2 
  1007 departure_8    arrival_8           3 
  1008 departure_9    arrival_9           1 
  1009 departure_10   arrival_10          2
```

**Query: find the "trip count"**

```
select D.id, D.surname, count(*) as trips_made
from driver D 
  join trip T on D.id = T.driver
group by D.id, D.surname ;

-- result
  ID SURNAME      TRIPS_MADE 
   1 driver_1              3 
   2 driver_2              4 
   3 driver_3              3
```

However, if you want to learn about triggers, you will find that a "row level trigger" will give you "mutating table" errors.  When using a "table level" trigger, you cannot reference :NEW and :OLD.  What you need is a COMPOUND TRIGGER.  You can find numerous discussions about this problem.  Apart from consulting the Oracle PL/SQL [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm), it may be worth your while looking that the examples written by T Hall eg [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/trigger-enhancements-11gr1), and S Feuerstein eg [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CGRC9SJRBTH83GTAAWUB1H4JG.html).

The dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=24ae3a5a7bf9802f6592da1dd60df2d0) contains the code used for this answer, and a third example table called DRIVERV2 plus examples of the above mentioned trigger types (and typical error messages).